# === returns false in Nashorn when both references should be pointing to the same object

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

Here's an example that demonstrates the problem I am facing:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine(
    new String[] { "-strict" }
);

try {
    engine.eval("function Foo(src) { this.src = src }; var e = { x: new Foo(\"what\") };");

    ScriptContext c = new SimpleScriptContext();
    c.setBindings(engine.createBindings(), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    c.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE).putAll(engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE));

    System.out.println(engine.eval("var z = e.x; z === e.x;", c));
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I'm aware that objects that were instantiated in another context, are considered "foreign" and end up being wrapped by a `ScriptObjectMirror` instance. I am assuming this is why I'm running into a problem here. I believe whenever `x` is dereferenced, a new `ScriptObjectMirror` instance is created; that's the only thing that can explain the following bit of code also returning `false`:

```
System.out.println(engine.eval("e.x === e.x;", c));
```

Is there a way around this? I'm looking for something I can do from Java to maybe set up up contexts/bindings a certain way instead of having to write code in JavaScript to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the benefit of others who may be reading this question here:

There is a discussion thread on this in nashorn-dev openjdk email alias:
 http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nashorn-dev/2015-December/005764.html

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer as Sundar has provided a good explanation in the mailing-list for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've seen the doc here: (https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+jsr223+engine+notes) but in case your assumption is correct maybe you could use 'Explicit script object mirror wrapping' to avoid the issue you have.

Comment: JavaScript objects are wrapped when you pass them into a foreign context, but the problem here is that `===` in Nashorn seems to be comparing the wrapper instances and not the actual, wrapped objects. If it sees that is a `ScriptObjectMirror` instance, it should unwrap it before comparing IMO. Unless there is something I'm missing.